# Удаление всего текста из поля редактирования в Groovy

Tags: groovy

Вот код:
.....................................................................................................................................................................

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import javax.swing.JOptionPane
def RimArab (Rim) {
Map rimArab = [ "I":1, "V":5, "X":10, "L":50, "C":100, "D":500, "M":1000]
f = Rim.replace("IV", "IIII").replace("IX", "VIIII").replace("XL", "XXXX").replace("XC", "LXXXX").replace("CD", "CCCC").replace("CM", "DCCCC")
Arab = 0; for(i in f) { Arab = Arab + rimArab[i]}; return Arab
                  }                 
swing = new SwingBuilder()
button = swing.button(text: 'Вычислить', actionPerformed: {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, RimArab(message.text))
})
button1 = swing.button(text: 'Очистить', actionPerformed: {//(message.text).replace(message.text, '')})
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, (message.text).replace(message.text, ''))
})
frame = swing.frame(title: 'Римские в арабские'){
    panel(){
    message = textField(columns: 12)
    widget(button)
    widget(button1)
}}
frame.pack()
frame.show()
```

...................................................................................................................................................................
Он переводит римские числа в в рабские. Я хочу сделать так что бы при нажатии кнопки 'Очистить' из поля редактирования удалялся весь текст. В данный момент 
происходит "очистка" вывода. Код в комментарии не делает ни чего.
Просьба предоставить исправление кода или подсказать направление "хода мыслей".

Исправление-дополнение: вместо (message.text).replace(message.text, '') намного лучше вставить message.cut() - меньше текста, понятнее и работает быстрее, но а конструкция с replace позволяет заменить любое значение переменной на что нибудь...

Answer (score 1):

```
button1 = swing.button(text: 'Очистить', actionPerformed: {         
                    message.selectAll()
                    message.cut()
})
```

А может быть вот так:

```
message.setText("")
```

Вместо

```
message.selectAll()
message.cut()
```

Comment: Что-то мне тут `cut` не нравится...